# Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 -MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, html-table

I am a beginner programmer and I have just started using MySQL - I am using a program called PHP MyAdmin to Create a table in a database. I want to enter in values and then have those values appear in a table. I have made a table called table 1 in a database called sweetshop. The two rows I put in the PHP MyAdmin program are called SweetID and SweetName.
I hope someone will be able to help. Sorry if I don't come across clear - I haven't been coding long!

The code I'm using for this particular section is:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sweetshop");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to Connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
} 

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table1");   

echo "<table> 
      <tr> 
        <th>Sweet ID</th> 
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>"; 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "  <td>" . $row['SweetID'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "  <td>" . $row['SweetName'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "</tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>"; 

mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure this code is causing that error?

Comment: Column count doesn't match value count can be in insert query only. This code can'to generate this error

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that the columns you have are named SweetID and SweetName
If so, change your select statement from

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table1");
```

to

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SweetID, SweetName FROM sweetshop.table1");
```

and you should be good (db name in your select isn't required but is a great habit to develop now).
Try running that exact select through phpMyadmin to see what your result set looks like as well, if you get results there then you should also get them from php

It would also be helpful for you to post the full structure of the table just in case